# Calling Constructors on Dojo Classes Extended with dojo.extend

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a class created using dojo.declare(). Sometimes, I want to add another module (also created with dojo.declare) but when I do, it doesn't seem to become part of the first class.

Here's a simplified example:

```
 dojo.declare( 'class1',
    null,
    {
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log( 'class1 constructor' );
            this.inherited(arguments);
        }
    }
);

dojo.declare( 'class2',
    null,
    {
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log( 'class2 constructor' );
        }
    }
);

dojo.extend( class1, class2 );

var myclass = new class1();
```

You can see a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdvRX/

I am aiming to duplicate this functionality:

```
dojo.declare( 'class2',
    null, 
    {
        _class2_prop: true,
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log( 'class2 constructor');
        }
    }
);

dojo.declare( 'class1',
    class2, // class2 added as parent/mixin/module type thing
    {
        _class1_prop: true,
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log( 'class1 constructor');
        }
    }
);
```

But only sometimes... Basically, I want to add to the second argument of class1's dojo.declare() dynamically. Depending on other factors, class2 may or not be used.

In the real-world version, each class is in a seperate file and loaded with dojo.require().

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dojo.extend receives [an object containing the properties to mix in](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/extend.html) instead of an extra class.

So you have to do

```
class1.extend({
    f2: function(){ console.log('class2'); }
})
```

or perhaps

```
class1.extend( class2.prototype )
```

I am not sure if you can do the same constructor-inheritance magic from dojo declare though. Perhaps you migh need to change that functionality to another method and/or do the inheritance manually

```
var oldF = class1.prototype.f
class1.extend({
    f: function(){
        olfF.call(this);
        console.log('more stuff');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be enough for your case, but maybie you could assign the class you want to extend your main class to a variable, like this :

```
dojo.declare( 'class2',
    null,
    {
        _class2_prop: true,
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log( 'class2 constructor');
        }
    }
);
// set this to whatever class you want to use for extending class1, or to null
var extendedClass = class2; 

dojo.declare( 'class1',
    extendedClass, // class2 added as parent/mixin/module type thing
    {
        _class1_prop: true,
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log( 'class1 constructor');
        }
    }
);


var myclass = new class1();
```